# ASP .NET MVC Ajax insert view instead instead replace data only first time

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm new to AJAX, and I have a very simple example, but has a problem; first call the data is duplicated at the View and in subsequent calls work correctly. What am I doing wrong?

The ~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml file had all scripts necesary:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
```

First time, the initial view:

[image: FirstTime]

Second time, first time button click inserts a number instead of replace number:

[image]

Third time, second time button click works fine but in the second line number... an so on:

[image]
This is my code:
Model

```
    namespace MQWebSt.Models
{
    public class AjaxTest
    {
        public int Number { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using MQWebSt.Models;

namespace MQWebSt.Controllers
{
    public class AjaxTestController : Controller
    {
        // GET: AjaxTest
        public ActionResult Vista()
        {
            AjaxTest at = new AjaxTest { Number = 1 };
            return View(at);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Vista( AjaxTest model)
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();

            model.Number = rnd.Next(1, 100);

            return PartialView("AjaxTestPartial", model);
        }
    }
}
```

View Vista.chtml:

```
@model MQWebSt.Models.AjaxTest

@{

    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";

}

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Vista", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "divEmp", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace }))
{
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-md glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right" name="Contestar" type="submit" value="+1"></button>

    <div class="panel panel-footer">
        <table id="divEmp">
            @Model.Number.ToString()
        </table>

    </div>

}
```

AjaxTestPartial.chtml:

```
@model MQWebSt.Models.AjaxTest
@Model.Number.ToString()
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you're using `InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace`, it's going to replace the data in the `UpdateTargetId`. You could use `InsertionMode.InsertBefore` instead and it would build the values out in the parent of `#divEmp`.  However, if you *need* the values to be placed in `#divEmp`,  you'll need to write a JavaScript handler for the `OnSuccess` option of your Ajax form, that way you can dictate if you're doing insert vs. pre-pend vs. replace.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is, your HTML markup code in your razor view is not valid. With the code you have, razor will generate the below markup (*Check the view source*)

```
<div class="panel panel-footer">
   1
   <table id="divEmp"></table>
</div>
```

You can see that 1 is not inside the table. It is outside. So when your ajax form submit happens, it will update the tables content with the new value. that is the reason you are still seeing the initial number.

The solution is to change the table to a div/span

```
<div id="divEmp"> @Model.Number.ToString() </div>
```

Or if you absolutely need to have a table for any reason, have the value inside a td and use "divEmp" as the id attribute value of that.

```
<table >
    <tr>
        <td id="divEmp">1</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```